# Is there a way to make an HTML5 anchor element calculate its href target "lazily"?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a large number (>300) of links in a page generated via GWT. Each one is a variant on the current URL and represents an additional actions.

I initially had custom widgets with custom click behaviors and custom context menus. However, users have asked to have real links with their standard behavior so usual things like the default shortcuts and link context menus work correctly.

The problem with this approach is that I have to build a full link for the href of each link during the render phase, which has a severe performance impact (verified via profiling).

I can attempt to hand-optimize the link generation, but I'd like to first check whether there might be a way to have the href attribute calculated "lazily" once the user has performed an action that depends on this href?

Comment: I don't think you can easily do what you're after. but having said that I don't see why they need to be generated during rendering. Why not render fully and then go through and update all the anchor targets. Means the page should appear quickly and then your link populating happens and hopefully it will be in the background and unnoticeable unless it is running very slow...

Comment: Another option along those lines might be to loop through smaller chunks of the array on a timer event.  This is a psuedo-threading technique sometimes used in flash applications to combat hangs in initialization, no reason it can't work in javascript.

Comment: I still find it very hard to believe that generating 300 URLs and putting them in the href attribute takes that long. If you show your code, we would have a better idea on what could possibly be done

Comment: Also, if you care at all about usability, don't display 300 links at once, specially in a single list!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate href in onclick event in HTML:

```
<script>
function fun(anchor) {
    anchor.href='http://google.com';
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="fun(this)">link</a>
```

But I don't now if it's fill your needs

Comment: This was my idea too, but you'll need to generate a JS function with all the 300 links, which would suffer the same problem. But in my head, generating 300 links should not take much time. Also, I tried it on jsfiddle and it didn't work http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/MMBtL/1